# Jquery autocomplete for input form, using Textpattern category list as a source

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, webforms, textpattern

I'm using the [Textpattern CMS](http://textpattern.com/) to build a discussion site-- I have a firm grasp of XHTML and CSS, as well as Textpattern's template language, but PHP and Javascript are a bit beyond my cunning.

On the input form to begin a new topic, users need to select a category from a list of over 5,000 options. Using the HTML `select`-type `input` element is very unwieldy, but it works. I would like to use some kind of Javascript magic to **display a `text`-type input element** that will read user input and **display matches or autocomplete from the available categories**, passing the required option's `value` into the appropriate database field.

I've seen several autocomplete plugins for jquery, but the instructions presuppose that you understand how Javascript works.

As I mentioned above, it's easy for me to generate the category list as a `select`-type `input` element, and I can hide that element using CSS. Is it possible to control select-list input using an autocomplete mechanism in a `text`-type input element? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the autocomplete to take its data from a URL, so I can see this being used in a couple nifty ways with Textpattern.

The array format that autocomplete uses looks like this:

```
["example_one", "example_two", ... ]
```

Since you have 5000+ elements, you might want to create a page that simply lists them using that format:

```
Page Autocomplete:
[
    <txp:article_custom form="array_form" ... />
]

Form array_form:
"<txp:title />",
```

To use this page instead of including all the items in a select field, you'd set up your autocomplete with:

```
$("#example").autocomplete("<txp:link_to_home />Autocomplete");
```

You can use a caching plugin to speed up loading.

To speed things up even more, you could use the Textpattern search function with a [custom display page](http://justinfrench.com/?id=15) instead of using a full listing. There may be a way to set up Autocomplete so that whenever a new character is entered/removed, autocomplete is reloaded with the new search string.

Comment: I finally got this working using the modifications posted here: http://forum.textpattern.com/viewtopic.php?pid=211878#p211878

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT : Updated to put option.value in a hidden field**

Yes, it is possible. For example, if you have the following html code :

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBoxId"></input>
<!-- added hidden field to store selection option value -->
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" name="selectedCategory"></input>
<select id="mySelectId" style="display: none">
    <option>Category 1</option>
    <option>Category 2</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

You can use following jquery code to put this data in an array :

```
var categories = $.map($("#mySelectId option"), function(e, i)
{
    return e; // Updated, return the full option instead its text
});
```

And finally, you can use an autocomplete plugin like [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) :

```
$("#myTextBoxId").autocomplete(categories,
{
    formatItem : function(item) { return item.text; } // Added
});
```

Check the [autocomplete plugin demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) to see what [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete) you can use (like autoFill and mustMatch).

All you have to do is put this in your html header (jquery js, autocomplete css & js, code for your page) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        // Updated script
        var categories = $.map($("#mySelectId option"),
            function(e, i) { return e; });
        $("#myTextBoxId").autocomplete(categories,
        {
            formatItem : function(item) { return item.text; }
        });
        // Added to fill hidden field with option value
        $("#myTextBoxId").result(function(event, item, formatted)
        {
            $("#myHiddenField").val(item.value);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Ok, it's only a few lines of code, but I don't really like the "select to array" stuff. If possible, you should create a page that that returns a list of categories matching user input (again, check the demo page for examples, unfortunatly, I can't help you much with Textpattern).

Of course, I didn't test, just put a comment if you have a question.
EDIT : I DID test, but not with 5k items in my `select` ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost there!

Using your recommendation, I can display a text `input` element, and generate a list of options on the fly from user input.

What I still need is to pass the option's `value` into the form. In my tests so far, the database is taking the value from the hidden select field.

Comment: Here's what I mean:
    <option value="category-value">Category Name</option>

The method you've given allows me to select a **Category Name** from the autocomplete drop-down, but the database draws **category-value** from the default selection on the hidden select menu.

Comment: Can javascript make a selection on the hidden input element based on user input in the autocomplete field? Or is it possible to change the `value` using some other method?

Comment: Hi, I modified the solution to match your requirements. I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you! The updated script no longer displays autocomplete options-- when I type, nothing happens. My javascript console shows a "SyntaxError: Parse error" between `});` and the closing `</script>` tag. Is this my mistake, or a typo?

Comment: I added `);` to the `}` on the line above, and autocomplete works again, but the hidden field would not pass selected value into the database. I got it working by using a text input instead of a hidden input-- I could visually verify that the input was entered, and it went to the database.